# WCF - Multiple Endpoints for REST and SOAP

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, soap

I am trying to code a WCF service with both REST and SOAP endpoints. I was initially using "TransportCredentialOnly" for the SOAP endpoints. As I started to add REST endpoints...I am using a third party OAUTH 1.0 class to provide security to the REST Service.

With the "TransportCredentialOnly" authentication, I had to enable "Windows Authentication" on the IIS Website Application.

The issue I am having is that the REST calls come back with a "Authentication failed" as IIS is expecting an initial authentication to happen with Windows Credentials before hitting the REST Endpoint.

I enabled "Anonymous Authentication" on the IIS application but still be prompted for Windows Credentials before proceeding.

Is there anyway to keep the "Windows Authentication" scheme for SOAP calls and have Anonymous authentication on the REST endpoints (which will proceed to use OAuth 1.0)? I don't really want to separate this out into two projects/services as some of the functions/methods/classes are universal between the SOAP and REST calls.

Here is my web config so far of attempts:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="DOMAIN\Security_Group"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="Anonymous">
            <security mode="None"/>
        </standardEndpoint>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
       <service name="service name">      
        <endpoint address="SOAP"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding"
                  contract="contract name">
          <identity>
             <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>        
        <endpoint address="REST"
                  kind="webHttpEndpoint"
                  binding ="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
                  endpointConfiguration="Anonymous"
                  behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"
                  contract ="contract name">
        </endpoint>   
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="service url"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>
        </behavior>    
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--<protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>-->
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept"/>-->
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**10-20-2015 Update**: I applied a new config to use serviceAuthorization in the web.config file

```
<service name="service name"  behaviorConfiguration="Oauth">
<endpoint address="service address"               
          binding ="webHttpBinding"
          behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"
          contract ="service contract">
</endpoint>
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="base address"/>
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
</service>

<behavior name="Oauth">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
  <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Assembly.OAuthAuthorizationManager,Assembly" />
</behavior>
```

Here is the OAuthorizationManager Class:

```
 public class OAuthAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        bool Authenticated = false;

        string normalizedUrl;
        string normalizedRequestParameters;

        base.CheckAccessCore(operationContext);

        // to get the httpmethod

        HttpRequestMessageProperty requestProperty = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)(operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage).Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];

        string httpmethod = requestProperty.Method;

        // HttpContext.Current is null, so forget about it 
        // HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current; 

        NameValueCollection pa = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(operationContext.IncomingMessageProperties.Via.Query);

        if (pa != null && pa["oauth_consumer_key"] != null)
        {
            // to get uri without oauth parameters
            string uri = operationContext.IncomingMessageProperties
            .Via.OriginalString.Replace
               (operationContext.IncomingMessageProperties
            .Via.Query, "");

            string consumersecret = "secret";

            OAuthBase oauth = new OAuthBase();

            string hash = oauth.GenerateSignature(
                new Uri(uri),
                pa["oauth_consumer_key"],
                consumersecret,
                null, // totken
                null, //token secret
                httpmethod,
                pa["oauth_timestamp"],
                pa["oauth_nonce"],
                out normalizedUrl,
                out normalizedRequestParameters
                );
            Authenticated = pa["oauth_signature"] == hash;
        }
        return Authenticated;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workable solution to have a REST based WCF service hosted in IIS can use its own custom Basic Authentication. You can easily send back a response header to challenge for Basic Authentication credentials, and just have IIS wired up to `"Anonymous Authentication."` In this case IIS will only take care of Hosting and that's it.

Create a custom Authorization manager class that inherits from `ServiceAuthorizationManager` and configure this to your service.

```
public class RestAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        //Extract the Authorization header, and parse out the credentials converting the Base64 string:
        var authHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];
        if ((authHeader != null) && (authHeader != string.Empty))
        {
            var svcCredentials = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII
                    .GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Substring(6)))
                    .Split(':');
            var user = new { Name = svcCredentials[0], Password = svcCredentials[1] };
            if ((user.Name == "user1" && user.Password == "test"))
            {
                //User is authrized and originating call will proceed
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //not authorized
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //No authorization header was provided, so challenge the client to provide before proceeding:
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"MyWCFService\"");
            //Throw an exception with the associated HTTP status code equivalent to HTTP status 401
            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

Add the above custom authorization manager to configuration:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="SecureRESTSvcTestBehavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
<serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="WcfRestAuthentication.Services.Api.RestAuthorizationManager, WcfRestAuthentication"/>
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Apply above behavior to only REST End points. Now IIS won't have control of any authorization here anymore. Make sure you use SSL certificate to secure the creds from being sent as plain text.

Comment: Hmmm, is there a way to use this methodology and apply it to OAuth? On the REST endpoints I have in place...they do a OAuth1.0 authentication with a consumer key and secret. This works...just wondering if there is anyway to use Anonymous Authentication on the IIS authorization to access the REST endpoint.

Comment: With some tweak request payload can be accessed in AuthorizationManager that are required by OAuth. If service is hosted in IIS the HttpContext.Current is accessible to WCF. So you can use it to fetch the incoming request and do what you can. ... And what do you mean by IIS Authorization?

Comment: Have a look at this sample of OAuth usage in ServiceAuthroizationManager. https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples/blob/master/src/OAuth/OAuthResourceServer/Code/OAuthAuthorizationManager.cs

Comment: IIS Authorization...I mean the "Authentication" settings in IIS under the application being hosted. So for the "Authentication" settings, I have "Windows Authentication" and "Anonymous Authentication" enabled. It seems when I try to send a GET to the WCF service, I get a "Not authorized" response as the IIS application is blocking the request due the "Windows Authentication" setting being enabled.

Comment: That's fine. If you have `Anonymous Authentication` with any other Auth type then that would not force windows authentication unless specified explicitly via configuration.

Comment: It seems that IIS is forcing Windows Auth though from what I can tell. Every GET request is coming back with a "401 - Unauthorized to directory or page" If I navigate in a browser to the WCF service page, I can supply Windows Auth credentials and then run the GET request and it will succeed (using Postman for testing). I also used debugging/attach to process in VS to verify that its hitting the new "serviceAuthoization" class I specified in the web.config file...and it is. I edited the initial post with a "10-20-2015 update of the new OAuthAuthorizationManager class I put in place.

Comment: I tried to host REST service with both Anon and Windows auth but it's working fine.

Comment: @JonathanMabrito have you tried removing the `base.CheckAccessCore(operationContext);` from the CheckAccessCore method? I doubt this will invoke the default authorization mechanism before your custom code.

Comment: I tried removing it with no success. I ran the service in Debug mode and put a breakpoint in the CheckAccessCore class and proceed to execute the GET statement. I do not see any hits happening. The moment I typed the WCF service URL in a browser, type in the Windows Credentials, and authenticated...the GET statements proceed to execute fine and the breakpoints in the CheckAccessCore class are hit.

Comment: ugh!! I see now.. you have Windows authentication enabled under `System.web`. Can you try removing this setting?

Comment: Removed it with no luck unfortunately. Still being prompted to authenticate.